# DB2 and ResultSetMetaData - Unable to get column name

Tags: java, database, db2

I am developping an application on WAS 8.0.0.5 that iteracts with a DB2 database.

I am getting the column name using java.sql.ResultSetMetaData call getColumnName() class. On my development WAS everything works great.

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1);
```

When I try and install on a WAS 8.0.0.6 instead of getting the column name, I get the column index!!!

The driver set for the connection string is **com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver**

As I side note, I've confirmed and WAS 8.0.0.5 uses DB2 driver 3.62 (works) and 8.0.0.6 uses 4.12 (doesn't work).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the response.

Unfortunately it wasn't the solution. The behavior was that the column index was being returned, instead of the query's label or column name itself.

The problem was that the db2jcc.jar version, configured on the WAS JDBC resources, was too old (version 3.59) I replaced it for 4.12 and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `getColumnName()` and `getColumnLabel()` has changed in the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC version 4. I believe it now conforms to the JDBC specification. You can use the connection property `useJDBC4ColumnNameAndLabelSemantics` to modify this behaviour, as explained here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0052593.html.

Comment: I was calling `getColumnName()` instead of `getColumnLabel()` and was not aware of the behavior change. Thanks for pointing me out.